# Question about vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

If I want to draw the lines of force to a vector field F and consider whether any results are physically reasonable, then i can start with to solve the differentiable equation

$$ y'(x)= {F_y(x,y) \over F_x(x,y)} $$

When I solve this differentiable eqution then I will find out the integral curve **for** the **vector field**. But how do I find out the field direction and "strength" for the vector field?? And if the i am taking the integral of avector field over a curve p
$$(1) \int_p F*dr$$
 and if this curve p is orthogonal against the integral curve **of the vectorfield**, then the result of the integral **(1)** will be zero, right?